# Does MySQL InnoDB locks multiple rows with READ_COMMITTED isolation level?

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.5, locking

I am in trouble while resolving `LOCK WAIT TIMEOUT EXCEED` error with MySQL InnoDB.

I have gone through [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels) and it says if we use isolation level `READ_COMMITTED` then my update query should lock only those rows which match the `WHERE` condition, but this is not working for me as I am getting `54` row locks for that query.

The result of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` is given below.

```
---TRANSACTION 8AE162608, ACTIVE 102 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 56 lock struct(s), heap size 6960, 54 row lock(s), undo log entries 135
MySQL thread id 18013536, query id 164766412915 localhost MyDataDb Updating
update stock set quantity = quantity + -1, last_updated_dts='2015-01-19 00:08:23', last_updated_by='vishal' where location = 1 and product_id = '123'
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 98 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
```

Why I am getting **54** row locked while my update query condition matches only **one row** and I am using **`READ_COMMITED`** isolation level?

**EDIT:** All columns used in where condition are indexed.
Please see my table structure here.

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `location_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `quantity` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_available` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F',
  `created_dts` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_updated_dts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_updated_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `FK_location` (`product_id`),
  KEY `availibility` (`location_id`,`is_available`,`quantity`),
  KEY `Index_4` (`last_updated_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_stock_2` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Please share the Query and the output from Explain.

Comment: If you have observed the question, `Quey` is already in innodb status :)

Comment: but Explain and Create table are missing - afaik innodb locks index entries, not rows, so actual number of locks depends on index used.

Comment: Hi, please see my updated question

Comment: "All columns used in where condition are indexed" - by multiple indexes or one multicolumn index? these things are important, thats why someone always asks for create table statement etc - it says such details exactly

Comment: Hello, please see my updated question